# MongoDB - How to convert the data structure of a column and store it in another column

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

There are 3 million rows in MongoDB.
I want to create column B using column A.

```
A : [1,2,3,4]
// All level value is 1
B : [
  { key: 1, level: 1 },
  { key: 2, level: 1 },
  { key: 3, level: 1 },
  { key: 3, level: 1 },
];
```

What I have tried:

```
table.update_many({}, [
    {
        "$set": {
            "B": {"key" : "$A", "level" : 1}
        }
    }
])
```

But this result is not what I want.

```
B : {"sku_id" : [1,2,3,4], "level" : 1}
```

Is there any way to bulk update? Or do I need to update one row at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$map` to iterate each element in the `A` array and transform into a new array with documents.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "B": {
        $map: {
          input: "$A",
          in: {
            "key": "$$this",
            "level": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S74nUrEbO3b)

Comment: Can you share a resource where I can read more about these functions?

Comment: [`$map`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)